# " Using switchCase with null "

Tags: java

I am trying to use message==null and  message!=null with switch case , but it gives me syntax error .
Here is the code

```
    String message = "Happy New Year ;)";
switch (message) {
case null :
    break;
case !null :
    System.out.println(message);
    break;
    default :           
}
```

I've done it with if{}else{} and it has no problem with it , but I don't know what is wrong with switchCase .

```
   if(message == null) {
     
 }else if (message != null) {
     System.out.println(message);
 }
```

Thank you for your response ❤

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't support using null in `switch` statements

> `Null` in `switch` case Java
> Java docs clearly stated that: The prohibition against using `null` as a `switch` label prevents one from writing code that can never be executed. If the `switch` expression is of a reference type, such as a boxed primitive type or an enum, a `run-time error` will occur if the expression evaluates to `null` at run-time

Comment: Thanks man , appreciate your answer .

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do `!null` in java since `null` is not of type `boolean`.

Instead, try checking for it before since you know you will not have entered the `else` clause if `message` was `null`.

```java
String message = "Happy New Year ;)";
if (message == null) {
  // error
}
else {
  switch (message) {
    case x:
      y();
      break;
    default:
      System.out.println(message);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: still error , because of the null keyword , but I think I should use the if_statement .

Comment: @TwanaStackoverflow edited! this should work now!